# find lat,long inside polygon with regular interval of time using mysql

Tags: mysql, geofencing

I have table latest location there i have lat and long with device id.
 one more table with fencing name,there i have polygon points.
 so now how i can check point lies inside polygon.
 i need this with regular interval of time and storing that to new table.
 so how to find this with MySQL function,event or with procedure?

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491938/mysql-spatial-query-to-find-whether-a-latitude-longitude-point-is-located-withi/25494127#25494127)?

Answer (score 1):

Create a trigger for your location table:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html and inside the trigger function use st_within